# How is the restricted mean upper limit in survival analysis calculated in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I conducted Kaplan Meier analysis in R looking at he survival of fibres in a fatigue test. I have not predefined the upper limit for the restricted mean. How does R calculate or decide the upper limit in order to calculate the restricted mean?
I am using the following code:

```
fit = survfit(Surv(cyclicdata[,1], cyclicdata[,2]) ~ cyclicdata[,3])
print(fit, print.rmean=TRUE,rmean="common")
```

Answer (score 1):

From experience with this calculation over the past few years, I believe that the restricted mean is by default calculated as the mean of the longest lives from each group.

For example, I have run into this with two groups having lives as below:

Group 1 Lives:

> 22  23  25  26  30  32  32  34  37  38  40  43  45  48  48  54 
>   56  59  60  62  70  72  73  73  76  77  78  78  82  86  86  92 
>   92  92  95  98  99 102 104 106 107 112 114 114 115 119 120 123
>   132 134 135 151 154 157 169 180

Group 2 Lives:

> 5   7  30  41  44  56  59  64  67  79  86 101 110 120 120 123
>   125 138 150 163 163 164 167 199 201 214 235 236 237 242 245 270
>   272 274 282 283 284 287 296 300 300 310 314 321 322 325 340 342
>   345 355 371 375 376 398 414 419 422 428 442 444 449 474 511 516 549
>   552 560 563 581 608 618 628 637 638 675 685 702 782 782 817 885
>   886 946 947 951

When I run my survival fit and print the output, I get this:

`* restricted mean with upper limit =  566`

This is equal to:

`> mean(max(c(Group1$Lives,Group2$Lives)))`

`[1] 565.5`

or

`> (951+180)/2`

`[1] 565.5`